# How t change wordpress admin from white to black?

Tags: wordpress

I started to use wordpress and noticed that my admin bar(the left side) is different from the youtube [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6EOuMDLj10) I watched.

How do I change it?

my admin bar(the left side):

[image: my admin bar(the left side)]

Comment: You are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting, and questions should include a summary of what you have tried so far and the relevant code. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using WordPress.com and not WordPress.org. Wordpress.com is hosted by WordPress and has a more limited feature-set than what is offered by the self-hosted solution via what is available at WordPress.org.

[This is a great comparison chart between the two](http://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/orgvscomv2.png) and the [full write-up](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/self-hosted-wordpress-org-vs-free-wordpress-com-infograph/).

Comment: Thanks. Is WordPress.org free too?

Comment: Yes, but you will need to have a host for the site (and domain). The host and domain are what you pay for.

Answer (score 0):

You may get some help from here
http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-change-the-admin-color-scheme-in-wordpress-3-8/
It's clearly given here how to do this. You may have many options after seeing this.
Please update if not helpful.